# c# switch: execute multiple blocks of code

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a char variable and that, according to its value, I need to execute some functions, following this schema:

```
Value  | Execute
-------+------------
A      | Func1
B      | Func2
C      | Func3
A or C | Func4
D      | Func5
B or D | Func6
-------+------------
```

So for example if v='A' I will run Func1 and Func4; if v='B' I will run Func2 and Func6.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
switch (v)
{
    case 'A': Func1(); break;
    case 'B': Func2(); break;
    case 'C': Func3(); break;
    case 'A': case 'C': Func4(); break;
    case 'D': Func5(); break;
    case 'B': case 'D': Func6(); break;
}
```

Is there something similar in c#?

Comment: `switch (v) { case 'A': Func1(); Func4(); break; case 'B': Func2(); break; case 'C': Func3(); Func4(); break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternate would be to use *two* switches:

```
switch (v)
{
    case 'A': Func1(); break;
    case 'B': Func2(); break;
    case 'C': Func3(); break;
    case 'D': Func5(); break;
}
switch (v)
{
    case 'A': case 'C': Func4(); break;
    case 'B': case 'D': Func6(); break;
}
```

But it will depend on what the cases and functions *are* as to what makes the most sense. For example, if the cases are defining workflows that define multiple related steps in order, then duplicating the "tasks" in the cases would make more sense. If the cases represent different states that define multiple *independent* tasks, then multiple switches might make more sense.

In the end, use whatever pattern you think makes the most sense to someone that is looking at it for the first time. If it's confusing to explain what's happening, then refactor into a pattern that makes more sense.

Answer (score 6):

The requirements are unnecessarily confusing.  They're focusing on the "Execute" part primarily, rather than the "Value" part.  Flip that focus and make "Value" the "key" of the requirements and it becomes more clear:

```
Value  | Execute
-------+------------
A      | Func1 and Func4
B      | Func2 and Func6
C      | Func3 and Func4
D      | Func5 and Func6
-------+------------
```

Then the code becomes obvious:

```
switch (v)
{
    case 'A':
        Func1();
        Func4();
        break;
    case 'B':
        Func2();
        Func6();
        break;
    case 'C':
        Func3();
        Func4();
        break;
    case 'D':
        Func5();
        Func6();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do switch statements above and it would work, but if you want to do something a bit different, you could use a dictionary here.  It would work something like this:

```
var calls = new Dictionary<char, List<Action>>
{
    { 'A', new List<Action> { Func1, Func4 },
    { 'B', new List<Action> { Func2, Func6 },
    { 'C', new List<Action> { Func3, Func4 },
    { 'D', new List<Action> { Func5, Func6 }
}
```

Then you could just do this:

```
foreach (var action in calls[v])
{
    action.Invoke();
}
```

If this table could grow and grow, this might be an easier way to manage it.  But it only works if all the functions are parameterless.